# How to update a custom object's specific custom field value on click of a submit button and it should get reflected in the objects data-table

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, json

I have a custom object Library__c, and a custom field Status__c and I am fetching it in the data table where if a user selects a checkbox and clicks on a submit button the Status__c field's default value should get changed from "In Progress" to "Submitted". To achieve this I have created a submit button and I am able to get the following response where on click of submit button I can see "Status__c": "Submitted". Now all I need to do is update this field in the object and display it in the data table. Can someone please help me out?

html code:

```
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick={dataHandler}> </lightning-button>&nbsp;<lightning-datatable key-field="Name" data={libList} columns={columns} draft-values={draftValues} onsave={savePocLibHandler}> </lightning-datatable>
```

js code:

```
dataHandler(event){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var selectedRecords =  
  this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();
  console.log("Before: Result1: " +selectedRecords);
  selectedRecords.forEach((x) => x["Status__c"]="Submit")
  console.log("After: Result1: " +selectedRecords);
  var chkStatus = JSON.stringify(selectedRecords)
  console.log("Result2: " +chkStatus);

  updatePoc({libList: this.libObject2})
  .then((result)=>{
    console.log("Result " +result);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
  
}
```

apex code:

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static string updatePoc(List<Library__c> libList){
    try {
        Database.update(libList, false);
        return 'Record Updated after onclick!';
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: Controller Code]